# C dynamic sized IO packages in embeded systems

Tags: c, io, embedded, nfc

In general I wonder how one would go about implementing a IO interface (i.e. NFC communication stack) with dynamically sized packages. I recently had to implement such a NFC stack and it (NFC-Dep) uses "I-Block" messages. They have the following structure:

| Name: | PCB | DID | Payload | CRC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Length: | 1 byte | 1 byte | 0 to 251 byte | 2 byte |

I had some ideas on how to do it for example:

```c
struct iblock{
    uint8_t PCB;
    uint8_t DID;
    const void *payload;
    size_t payload_size;
    uint8_t CRC[2];
};
```

Then I could read the values for the header from the buffer but would have to reference into the buffer for the payload. Is there a better way to do this if i can't use dynamic memory. Or what is the commonly accepted way to do something like this?

Thanks a lot for your replies and suggestions.

Comment: What is `PCB` and `DID`? I would expect one of them to contain payload size.

Comment: Since the payload is at most 251 bytes, you can have a `uint8_t payload[251];` to avoid dynamic memory.

Comment: NFC uses the different format. It is called NDEF. Your format **has** to have payload size information.

Answer (score 2):

`uint8_t package [256];` is the only portable solution. Use a size variable to keep track of how much of the buffer and/or payload that is actually used. And yes, it only makes sense to allocate the memory statically since your program must support the worst case of max payload. So you can't "save memory" by just allocating a bit of memory now and then. (Also, heaps don't actually save memory on single core MCU systems because that's not how they are implemented.)

Structs are problematic because of alignment & padding. In particular, your code will not work well on 32 bit targets. If you insist on using a struct then you probably have to write serialization/deserialization routines that fills up the struct from a raw buffer.

Also why would you const qualify the payload? That probably doesn't make any sense since you have to fill that one up with data repeatedly.

Comment: Like Lundin mentions I would also advice to serialize your data. You can use something like Protobuf (NanoPB or EmbeddedProto) to store your data. By using protobuf you bypass the alignment/padding issues and it makes your code backwards compatible. EmbeddedProto as a simplified example storing data on an NFC tag: https://embeddedproto.com/nfc-example-with-embedded-proto/